# PHP json_encode isn't seperating records correctly, consistantly

Tags: php, database

I am having some strange results with this code.  I am NOT a PHP programmer, so am just trying to limp my way through this.

The problem I am running into is that the separator between the records is being returned incorrectly in only some of the records...

```
    if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{

 $resultArray = array();
 $tempArray = array(); 

 while($row = $result->fetch_object())
 {
    $dist = sprintf("%f", distance($Lon,$Lat,$row->Longitude,$row->Latitude,"M")); 
    $row->Distance=$dist;
    $tempArray = $row;

        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
 }

}
```

About every 3rd record, starting between the 1st and 2nd, instead of the records being separated with a , there is ][

When I copy the results from json_encode, and correct these handful of seperators by hand, I am able to decode the json just fine.

Any idea what I am doing wrong in this code?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
-Larry

Comment: You can debug with `var_dump($resultArray);` to see what you are working with. It sounds like you have nested arrays causing the extra brackets. `json_encode()` itself will ***never*** make invalid json.

Comment: Also, move `echo json_encode($resultArray);` to OUTSIDE your `while` loop (which is probably the whole cause of your problem haha).

Comment: You were absolutely correct. The echo inside the while loop was causing the problem. I can't believe I did that :)  THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're outputting the entire result set for every row. Append the rows to `$resultArray` in the loop, then encode and output afterward. Also, you don't need `$tempArray`, and `array_push()` is not advised for adding a single item to an array.

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    $resultArray = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $dist = sprintf("%f", distance($Lon,$Lat,$row->Longitude,$row->Latitude,"M")); 
        $row->Distance = $dist;
        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to simplify this.  I have been programming for many years, but never in PHP, so I am going through all the beginner learning curve again :) I pieced that code together through trial and error looking at different snippets all over the internet :)

Comment: @LarryDietzII I think that's how a lot of us got started in PHP. Unfortunately there's a lot of really bad PHP code out there. Fortunately the official documentation is great, and there are other really good resources available. Check out https://phptherightway.com

Comment: Thanks for that site. I will take a look at it.